# Python how do I print the contents of 2 or more text files side by side?

Tags: python, file

Say I have a couple of text files, `fruit.txt` and `veg.txt` which look like,

```
Apple
Pear
Orange

Brocolli
Cucumber
Spinach
```

I have a couple of for loops that print out the contents of the .txt files,

```
       for line in fruit:
            fields = line.split("\n")   
            col = fields[0]
            print(col)
        for line in veg:
            fields = line.split("\n")   
            col1 = fields[0]
            print(col1)
```

And the output I get is,

```
Apple
Pear
Orange
Brocolli
Cucumber
Spinach
```

I want to try and print it side by side like,

```
Apple Brocolli
Pear Cucumber
Orange Spinach
```

Comment: are fruit and veg the same size?

Comment: Look at the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Comment: `[x for x in zip(fruit,veg)]`

Comment: In this example yes, but I also have a few other text files with uneven lengths, e.g. 3 fruits and 4 veg.

Comment: The duplicate still stands. Use the `itertools.zip_longest(...)` example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `format` method in builtin strings, and `zip_longest`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
...
# Assuming fruit is file_context.readlines()
fruits = fruit.split("\n")
vegs = veg.split("\n")
for l1,l2 in zip_longest(fruits, vegs, fillvalue=""):
    print("{}\t{}".format(l1, l2))
```

`zip_longest` will take care of the situation where you have unequal number of fruits and vegs.

NOTE: The above will work in python 3. For python 2, remember to replace:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
```

with:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to use the readlines method like so, and the 'end' parameter is the printed value that prints at the end, by default its value is '\n'

```
fruits = fruit.readlines()   
vegs = veg.readlines() 

for i in range(min(len(vegs),len(fruits))):
    print(fruits[i],end="\t")
    print(vegs[i])
```

Comment: For this method, I am assuming it doesn't work for uneven lists? Because I get an IndexError when I try.

Comment: This should work for uneven lists because "i" is actually taking the "min" value of "len(fruits)" and "len(vegs)", make sure you copied the min part.